# JavaFX how to fix misalignment of the Tableview header and table?

Tags: java, css, javafx

ive made a table in javaFX but the body of the table on the left is misaligned with the table header

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO8VC.png)
when is get rid of the css stylesheet it dosent have the misaligment but with the css stylsheet it does

if the problem is the css this is my css code

```
.table-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.table-view .column-header-background .filler {
    -fx-background-color: transparent
}

.table-view .corner {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .column-header-background{
    -fx-background-color: #263F73;
    -fx-background-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    -fx-background-insets: 0 11px 0 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 0 5px 0;
    -fx-text-background-color: WHITE;
 }

.table-view .column-header {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .table-cell{
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-padding: 2 0 2 10px;

}
.table-row-cell: hover {
    -fx-background-color: #93f9b911;
    -fx-text-background-color: red;
}
.table-row-cell: odd{
    -fx-background-color: #93f9b911;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
}
.table-row-cell: even{
    -fx-background-color: #1dbbdd11;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-padding: 0.0em;
}

.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:vertical,
.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:vertical .track,
.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:vertical .track-background,
.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:horizontal,
.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:horizontal .track,
.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar:horizontal .track-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar .increment-button,
.table-view .virtual-flow .scroll-bar .decrement-button {
    -fx-opacity: 0;
    -fx-padding: 2;
}

.table-row-cell:selected .text {
       -fx-fill: red ;
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly setting a background insets of 11px on the right of the column header background. Isn't that exactly what the arrow in your image is pointing at?

Comment: Greatly customized table styles are a difficult and advanced CSS exercise.  You have to really understand what you are doing to avoid errors.   I encourage beginners to avoid such a task.  There is some advice from Eden coding: [How to style a TableView in JavaFX](https://edencoding.com/style-tableview-javafx/) and [CellFactory: Complete Customization of JavaFX TableView](https://edencoding.com/tableview-customization-cellfactory/).